# Powershell - Using invoke-command in a for loop

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

When i try to run invoke-command for every computer in Active-Directory , i will encounter the following error :
"Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings. "

````
    ```
      $Hosts_Array=Get-ADComputer -Properties CN -Filter * | Sort-Object  | Select-Object CN
          foreach ($i in $Hosts_Array) {
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -Name "sysmon64"} 
           }
    ```
````

I use the For loop to run the command for every computer that fetch from the AD.

Comment: `Select-Object` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` or inside your loop use `-ComputerName $i.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, `Select-Object` returns **objects**, in this case objects with just one property called 'CN'.

In fact, you don't need to ask for the CN at all, because `Get-ADComputer` returns these properties by default:
`DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID,  UserPrincipalName`

You can simplify your code by doing:

```
$Hosts_Array = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name | Sort-Object
foreach ($computer in $Hosts_Array) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -Name "sysmon64" } 
}
```

`(Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name` returns a **string** array of just the computer names, which can also be done using `Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

P.S. I have changed the variable name to iterate with from `$i` (usually used in numbered loops) into `$computer` to make it clearer

<sup>Each object in AD has a `Relative Distinguished Name` (RDN). This is the name of the object in it's parent OU/Container. For user, group, computer, and container objects, the RDN is the value of the `cn` attribute (Common Name). For OU objects, the RDN is the value of the `ou` attribute. For domain component objects, it's the `dc` attribute.

The `Name` property returns the RDN of any object.</sup>

Comment: It works . Thank you but i just got confused what is the problem with CN instead of Name ? when i echo CN it returns strings like computer name exactly . So how CN differs from  Name while both are same in characters and structure ?

Comment: @SeyedMuhammadAlavi Each object in AD has a `Relative Distinguished Name` (RDN). This is the name of the object in it's parent OU/Container. For user, group, computer, and container objects, the RDN is the value of the `cn` attribute (Common Name). For OU objects, the RDN is the value of the `ou` attribute. For domain component objects, it's the `dc` attribute. The `Name` property returns the RDN of any object. You could indeed use `CN` in your code, but that would require you to ask for this extra property where there is really no need to.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you place invoke-command into try/catch block?

```
$Hosts_Array=Get-ADComputer -Properties CN -Filter * | Sort-Object  | Select-Object CN
    foreach ($i in $Hosts_Array) {
        try{
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -Name "sysmon64"}
        }
        catch{
            write-output("Unable to resolve $i ")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `invoke-command`, as `Get-Service` can be used to connect to computers remotely.

If you prefer to use `get-service`, then you can try the following script:

```
$Hosts_Array = Get-ADComputer -Properties * -Filter *

$Obj = @()
$ServiceName = "sysmon64"
foreach ($Computer in $Hosts_Array) 
{
    $Hostname = $computer.name
    
    # Check if computer is online
    write-host "pinging $Hostname" -for Cyan
    $ping = Test-Connection $Hostname -Count 1 -Quiet

    if ($ping)
    {
        write-host "Computer found - $Hostname" -ForegroundColor Green
        $Service = $null
        $Service = Get-Service $ServiceName -ComputerName $Hostname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        if ($ServiceName)
        {
            write-host "Service $ServiceName found - $Hostname" -ForegroundColor Green
            # create a hash table to store the date
            $Hash = @{
                Hostname = $Hostname
                ServiceName = $Service.Name
                Displayname = $Service.DisplayName
                Status = $Service.Status
            }

            $Obj += New-Object psobject -Property $hash
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "Service NOT $ServiceName found - $Hostname" -ForegroundColor red
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
    write-host "Computer found - $Hostname" -for Red
    }
}

$Obj
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most common powershell question.  Dereference the CN property into a string with foreach or select -expand or .CN and it will work.  I would run the whole list at once so it runs in parallel.

```
$hosts_array = Get-ADComputer -Properties CN -Filter * | Sort-Object |
  foreach-object CN
invoke-command $hosts_array { get-service sysmon64 }
```